# uiviewcontroller alloc changes setter/getter value when accessed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, setter, init

Ok, so i've been trying to figure this out and I have no idea... Basically, i have two classes in my ios application, the first is my main view and the second is a class to store some variables.  I have a switch and when the switch's state is changed, it sets the boolean getter/setter variable in the other class to that state.  Then I get the value and print it in the log.  However what i've noticed is that each time a call the viewcontroller using the code:

```
StoredVars *stored = [[StoredVars alloc]init];
```

the value defaults to 0...  To show this, I added a second instance of the viewcontroller call and the two log calls print out different values.  Switchy is the bool setter/getter in the second class "StoredVars". Can someone please explain why this is happening?  below is the code in my first class's .m file:

```
StoredVars *stored = [[StoredVars alloc]init];
[stored setSwitchy:(_toggle.on)];
NSLog(@"%d", [stored switchy]);
StoredVars *stored2 = [[StoredVars alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%d", [stored2 switchy]);
```

If I turn the switch on, the first log prints a 1, the second prints a 0.  if i turn the switch off, they both print 0.

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
StoredVars *stored = [[StoredVars alloc]init];
```

Is destroying whatever is previously stored in your `stored` variable and creating a brand new object, in other words, each time you call this line, the previous contents of 'store' are destroyed. You need to initialize it only once (maybe in your ViewController's `init` method), and keep using it **without** re-initializing it.

```
[stored setSwitchy:(_toggle.on)];
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to access that 'stored' variable from more than one class without the value being destroyed.

Comment: That's my point! Every time you call 'init' you're destroying it, so don't use it! (use it only at the beginning of your program)

Comment: can you give me an example of how i would go about declaring it? im not too familiar with going about it...

Comment: This is very basic information, if you're not following me so far, I suggest you to read a tutorial and also read about basic Objective-C language.

Answer (score 0):

the setter and getter is like this:

```
    - (void)setSwitchy:(BOOL)bSwitchy
    {

       _bSwitchy = bSwitchy;
    }

    - (BOOL)switchy
    {

       return _bSwitchy;
    }
```

so the property value is changing in setter.
the second prints a 0 ,that is you have not call the setter,then you the getter will retun the default value.

by the way ,stored and stored2 are totally two objects.

Answer (score 0):

I know that You have Two ViewController Right.

So i Will Call them Viewcontroller in which the Switch is placed.
and AnotherviewController where you want switch Effect.

1) in Viewcontroller When switch value changed > place this code.

```
 AnotherViewController *anotherVc=[[AnotherViewController alloc]init];
    [anotherVc setToggle:sw];  //sw will be your switch changed value.
```

2) in Anotherview Controller.h file

```
 @interface AnotherViewController : UIViewController
{
      int  _toggle;

}
@property(nonatomic,assign)int toggle;
```

3) Synthesize toggle
   and in AnotherviewController.m file

```
   -(void)setToggle:(int)toggle1{
    toggle=toggle1;
}
```

4) In viewWillAppear or any where
   you can check

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    if(toggle)
        swithlbl.text=@"YES";
    else
        swithlbl.text=@"NO";
}
```